# application.css and application.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, asset-pipeline, unicorn

I just upgraded my nginx from 1.4.2 (/usr/local) to 1.4.7 (yum) on AWS EC2. I now have a pair of errors occuring on the client side:

```
GET https://subdomain.mysite.com/assets/application.css net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 
GET https://subdomain.mysite.com/assets/application.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

I am at a loss for this and google has not been much help. Any ideas on where to start? All help appreciated. Could the switch from a manual install to a yum install be the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can confirm answer 1 addresses the underlying problem (I'm a new SE user so I can't upvote it yet). Here is more detail for search engines:

From `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2014/04/30 08:07:48 [crit] 35135#0: *116437 open() "/var/lib/nginx/proxy/7/09/0000001097" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream
```

In my case this happened because I recently changed the user under which nginx runs (the default nginx config uses `www-data` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`).

My solution was to `chown -R correct_user:root /var/lib/nginx/proxy`. I imagine I could also have `rm -rf`'d the existing `/var/lib/nginx/proxy` subdirectories with the expectation that nginx would recreate them using the `correct_user` as owner.

eric-francis thanks for figuring this out! This easily saved me a day of hunting.

Answer (score 7):

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

You may see something like:

> "/usr/local/var/run/nginx/proxy_temp/9/04/0000000049" failed (13:
>   Permission denied) while reading upstream

Heres how I fixed:

```
sudo nginx -s stop
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/nginx/*
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so this can be fixed in a couple of ways. The thing to do is check your log file.

Mine was located at `/usr/share/nginx/log/error-appname.log`

Tail the log and you will find that user defined in your config file (mine is at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) most likely does not have permissions to something. I use user `nobody`.

For one app I had to give `u+rx` (nginx needs executable) to my application user's home folder all the way to my application's public assets directory.

On another server, `nobody` was not able to write to nginx's `/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy` folder. So I had to `chown nobody /var/lib/nginx` down to the `/proxy` folder `nobody` was trying to write to.